# If the husband is fasting for Ramadan and the wife is not fasting, is it permissible to have sex?

Tags: sawm, sex, ramadan

If the husband is fasting for Ramadan and the wife is not fasting, is it permissible to have sexual intercourse without ejaculation? If anyone did like that due to misguidance, what is the rule in Islam?

Answer (score 6):

Three points must be considered:

- If there has been intercourse with penetration then that would invalidate fast no matter if there was an ejaculation or not as it is haram (by [Quran](http://legacy.quran.com/2/187) and [sunna](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/25) which explains why this verse have been revealed) to have intercourse (with penetration) while fasting.
- If there was only fondling or any kind of intimacy without penetration then the fast is valid, as long as there is no ejaculation (See for example [this](https://islamqa.info/en/107335) fatwa).
- If he didn't know it is/was haram or forget that he was fasting, then according to [this fatwa](http://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/60089/%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9-%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AC%D8%AA%D9%87-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B6%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85) in Arabic he should complete his day and there's nothing to do for him except repenting. This fatwa is based on qiyas on people who ate or drunk forgetfully while fasting according the sahih [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/40) or on the more general statement of [this](http://sunnah.com/urn/1321220) hadith.
  **Note** that if  any of them were fasting and knew the rule and did this bad deed by intention, they would need to re-fast that day and perform a [kafara](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/43) (freeing a Muslim and if this isn't possible to them, fasting two consecutive months, or feeding 60 poor Muslims if they couldn't fast two successive months).

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 3):

> Husband in fasting and wife is not fasting, then is it allowed to do
>   sexual intercourse without ejaculation.

In this case, the husband's fast will be broken. Sexual intercourse during the day in Ramadan (while fasting) is haram. The fast is broken even if he didn't ejaculate.

> If any one did like that due to misguidance, what is the rule in
>   Islam.

There is no sin on him. If someone commits a sin without knowing that it is a sin, he will not be accountable for it.

Answer (score 3):

If husband/wife is in fast then only his/her fast will be broken. But the patience will be beneficial. If you can't then the fast of that person will be broken.
If a you did it in any misguidance then you have not done any sin because it is clear in Islam that "if you do something wrong and you don't know about the sin then it is not sin but if you know that it is sin and you do it then you have done sin"

Answer (score -1):

Praise be to Allah.

Intercourse during the day in Ramadaan is haram for men and women alike, who are obliged to fast during the day.